# MonoDroid installation issue

Tags: android, windows-8, xamarin.android

During the installation process, it looks like Monodroid installer can't detect the Android-SDK that is already installed in my machine. It was already installed on "D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk" and already working fine with Eclipse.

Upon checking the installation log, it can't detect API 7, 8, 10, and 12, but 14 got detected. All of the APIs' "SDK Platform" and "Sources for Android SDK" are already installed.

Even "Android SDK" v. 20 can't be detected, but I already have rev. 20.0.3 installed.

When I try to continue, it downloads the whole Android SDK installer.

How to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18317) if the directory in which Android SDK is installed contains spaces (in your case "Program Files (x86)")you might run into some issues specially with the emulator, would you check and see if you can suppress this issue relocating the SDK to a path with no spaces in it.

You might also want to try installing it offline, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118684/mono-for-android-offline-installer).

Comment: instead of moving or copying you can also make a [symbolic link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) of the SDK in the desired destination e.g. _"c:\"_

Comment: Sorry for late response. I just figured out that Xamarin maintains their own copy of Android-SDK to avoid conflict in versions.